# Delphi CGI (IIS 7.5, Win 7): The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: delphi, iis, file-io, cgi

I have a CGI application (Delphi 7). At some point it goes through this code:

```
FileMode := fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite;
AssignFile( user_file, FULL_PATH_TO_USER_INFO_FILE_NAME);
{$I-} Reset( user_file, sizeof( TUserInfoRec));
//
// some IOResult checking here.. 
//
Result := FileSize( user_file) - 1;
CloseFile( user_file);
```

The application works fine on Windows XP SP3 with IIS 5.1. On Windows 7 with IIS 7.5 it can't open the file. The error appears at the Reset line - "The system cannot find the file specified." However, if I try to write to it using TIniFile it works.

```
ini_file := TIniFile.Create( FULL_PATH_TO_USER_INFO_FILE_NAME);
ini_file.WriteString( 'Section','Ident','Value') ;
```

I assume it has to do with IIS permission, but after searching high and low, I'm out of ideas.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does USER_INFO_FILE_NAME contains the full path to file?
TIniFile by default creates it in Windows folder, so it doesn't need full path.

Comment: Yes, it does contain the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that user, on behalf of which IIS acts, has NTFS permissions on this file.